# using custom page for 403 Forbidden in pyramid

Tags: pyramid, http-status-code-403

I have seen the documentation but i am not able to make it working.If anyone could explain me more clearly how to create a custom 403 page in pyramid,it would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a renderer to your `@forbidden_view_config()` decorator:
`@forbidden_view_config(renderer='myforbiddentemplate.mako')`

Or, you could probably also do some sort of custom views, too:

`from pyramid.httpexceptions import (
    HTTPFound,
    HTTPNotFound,
    HTTPForbidden,
    HTTPBadRequest,
    HTTPInternalServerError
    )`

`@view_config(context=HTTPNotFound, renderer='HTTPNotFoundPage.mako')
def my_view(request):`

Answer (score 0):

Just decore your view with forbidden_view_config:

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='login-page.mako')
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='login-page.mako')
def login_view(request):
    return {}
```

Comment: i want a custom html page for it . please tell where to include what.

thanks

Comment: I edited my response, take a look. There's a complete solution.

Comment: i am still not able to do it
maybe because i am still writing raise HTTPForbidden() ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied wrong example. I'm using this one on my site, it redirects user with no enough permissions to login page.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyramid.view import forbidden_view_config


@forbidden_view_config(renderer='your_template_name')
def forbidden_view(request):
    request.response.status = 403
    return {}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. OP is asking for an explanation here as well.